# Using csharp-mode and Mono

Tags: c#, macos, emacs

I'm using csharp-mode in Emacs 23 on OS X. I'd like to get the flymake syntax checking working but I'm not familiar enough with emacs lisp to know where to change things in the [csharp-mode.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/csharp-mode.el) file to change the compiler. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Wow, I would hate to be stuck writing C# code without the concession of the convenience of Intellisense. You should really use Visual Studio.

Comment: Sometimes I don't want to wait for my VS VM to launch and then wait for VS to launch. Sometimes, it's just a few lines of change in a few files and emacs + etags does the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add the following to your Emacs init file, that should do the job:

```
(add-hook  'csharp-mode-hook 'flymake-mode)
```

From [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlymakeCsharp):

> History The original flymake-for-csharp came from a Blog Post on MSDN.
>   It has since been generalized, updated, and made more reliable and
>   flexible. In May 2011, it was integrated into csharp-mode itself.

In order to change the compiler, you can add a comment at the top of your C# code:

```
// flymake: csc.exe /t:module /R:MyAssembly.dll @@FILE@@
```

For more detail on options for changing the compiler, see the comments in the csharp-mode.el source file (search for "csharp-flymake-get-cmdline").

EDIT: Ok, based on your comment below about not wanting to put the flymake comment line in your C# code, I've come up with an alternative solution. Put the following code in your Emacs init file. Change the `(setq my-csharp-default-compiler "mono @@FILE@@")` line to whatever compile line you want. Now, whenever you open a C# file, you should be able to use flymake without adding the comment line into your C# source. If, at some later stage, you want to use the standard csharp-mode mechanism (of looking for a flymake comment in the C# source file), you just have to change the statement to (setq my-csharp-default-compiler nil).

```
;; Basic code required for C# mode
(require 'flymake)
(autoload 'csharp-mode "csharp-mode" "Major mode for editing C# code." t)
(setq auto-mode-alist  (append '(("\\.cs$" . csharp-mode)) auto-mode-alist))

;; Custom code to use a default compiler string for all C# files
(defvar my-csharp-default-compiler nil)
(setq my-csharp-default-compiler "mono @@FILE@@")

(defun my-csharp-get-value-from-comments (marker-string line-limit)
  my-csharp-default-compiler)

(add-hook 'csharp-mode-hook (lambda ()
                              (if my-csharp-default-compiler
                                  (progn
                                    (fset 'orig-csharp-get-value-from-comments
                                          (symbol-function 'csharp-get-value-from-comments))
                                    (fset 'csharp-get-value-from-comments
                                          (symbol-function 'my-csharp-get-value-from-comments))))
                              (flymake-mode)))
```

Comment: I've RTFM'd as well (as horrible as TFM is), but I wasn't sure if there was a better way so I don't have to modify every file in this solution with something that amounts to line noise.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear from your original post that that was what you wanted. I've modified my answer to provide a solution that will let you specify a "default compile command" to use without having to put the flymake comment in every C# source file.

Comment: I see how I could have worded that better. Thanks for helping out with my emacs n00bness.

Comment: Ack, spoke too soon. Flymake still generates syntax check errors... Nope, I just can't spell. This works, thanks.